# Using vscode, why can't I compile when both "iosteam" and "stdio.h" are included?

Tags: c, compilation, mingw-w64

When I declare  and   at the same time, vscode can't complie the file and there is the error log:

```
    > Executing task: C:\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g d:\CODES\C++\try\main.cpp -o d:\CODES\C++\try\main.exe <

C:\Users\16337\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqDR0fO.o: In function `__tcf_0':
C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:\Users\16337\AppData\Local\Temp\ccqDR0fO.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/include/c++/iostream:74: undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My code is very simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    printf("print something");
    return 0;
}
```

Dev-C++ can compile that code properly.

If I delete `#include <iostream>`, it can be properly compiled.

Comment: C is not C++ is not C. You need to know which programming language you are using and from there pick a compiler accordingly. And then finally write code in the language you picked, not in another language.

Answer (score 5):

`<iostream>` is a standard C++ header, so you need a C++ compiler and linker to use it. `gcc` is smart enough to compile `.cpp` files as C++, however it won't link the standard library into your program, hence the undefined references.

You need to use `g++`, which will link the standard C++ library by default, as Dev-C++ does.